# sshfs mount failing using fabric run command

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, sshfs

I am trying to mount the SSHFS using the following run command

> run("sshfs -o reconnect -C -o workaround=all localhost:/home/test/ /mnt")

and it is failing with the following error

> fuse: bad mount point `/mnt': Transport endpoint is not connected

However if i demonize it works. Is there any work around?.

Comment: I would check program privilages to `/mnt` folder. Or I would use `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out finally there is an issue with SSH and need to pass pty=False flag.

> run("sshfs -o reconnect -C -o workaround=all localhost:/home/test/
>   /mnt",pty=False)

Comment: What if you need to pass a password?